# CTAS to my local table using Snowflake Data Share

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am very new to Snowflake, and I have to answer a question whether I can load data into local database table using data share from different account.

e.g:
I have database db1 which has emp table locally and I have consumer access to share1 which table emp table,

How I can load data into local emp table using shared emp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More to Gokhan's answer, if you can READ it, you can save a copy to your own table. Via INSERT, CTAS, UPDATE, MERGE

BUT the point of Data Sharing is to avoid the pointless, "take a copy every night" and pay for a second copy of the data model, and pay for the "keep it in sync" computations, that is what so much of ETL is.

With more intent to migrate to "this other group/company/etc has some data", they update it, and pay the storage costs, and I read it when needed.

But again if the shared data is too verbose, or needs processing, sure this can need to also happen. And then you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shared objects as a read-only data source, so you can use

```
INSERT emp SELECT * FROM shared_database.schema_name.emp
```

or if you want to create a table, you may use CTAS:

```
CREATE TABLE emp SELECT * FROM shared_database.schema_name.emp
```

Maybe you can check this one:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html